# Could not find powermock-api-support-sources.jar during testCompileJava

Tags: powermock, junit5

While running tests in my project, I am getting the following error. We are unsure why the build is looking for source jar files.

```
04:15:21 > Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
04:15:28 > Task :compileJava FROM-CACHE
04:15:28 > Task :processResources
04:15:28 > Task :classes
04:15:31 > Task :bootWar
04:15:31 > Task :war SKIPPED
04:15:31 > Task :assemble
04:15:32 > Task :checkstyleMain FROM-CACHE
04:15:32 > Task :compileTestJava FAILED
04:15:32 
04:15:32 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
04:15:32 
04:15:32 * What went wrong:
04:15:32 
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
04:15:32 > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
04:15:32    > Could not find powermock-api-support-sources.jar (org.powermock:powermock-api-support:2.0.2).
04:15:32      Searched in the following locations:
04:15:32          file:/data/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-api-support/2.0.2/powermock-api-support-2.0.2-sources.jar
04:15:32    > Could not find powermock-core-sources.jar (org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.2).
04:15:32      Searched in the following locations:
04:15:32          file:/data/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-core/2.0.2/powermock-core-2.0.2-sources.jar
04:15:32    > Could not find powermock-reflect-sources.jar (org.powermock:powermock-reflect:2.0.2).
04:15:32      Searched in the following locations:
04:15:32          file:/data/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/2.0.2/powermock-reflect-2.0.2-sources.jar
04:15:32 
04:15:32 * Try:
04:15:32 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I am copying the `dependencies.gradle` snippet

```
    compile 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0'
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.0"
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.0"
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-mockito-release-full', version: '1.6.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-support', version: '2.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-reflect', version: '2.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
```

I am using java 11 ,springboot 2.0.5 and junit 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, we found that this is because one of the powermock libraries is still referring to junit 4, and it added some unwanted dependencies. So, we cleaned up the test dependencies, also avoided the libs that have `PowerMockRunner`. And that fixed the issue. Please find the latest `dependencies.gradle` snippet below,

```
 testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test', version: springBootVersion) {
     exclude (module: 'junit')
 }
 testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version: springVersion
 testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: springBootVersion) {
     exclude(module: 'commons-logging')
 }

 compile 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0'
 testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.3.2'
 testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: '5.3.2'
 testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: '5.3.2'

 testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.23.4'
 testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0'
```